# Does ANSI-C not know the inline keyword?

Tags: c, inline, c89

When compiling something as simple as

```
inline int test() { return 3; }

int main()
{
 test();
 return 0;
}
```

with `gcc -c test.c`, everything goes fine. If the `-ansi` keyword added, `gcc -ansi -c test.c`, one gets the error message

```
test.c:1:8: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘int’
```

This is true even if the C99 standard is explicitly selected, `gcc -std=c99 -ansi -c test.c`.

What is the reason for this, and is there a recommended fix?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use:

```
gcc -std=c99 -c test.c
```

The [`-ansi` flag specifies c90](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

> The -ansi option is equivalent to -std=c90.

ANSI C was effectively the 1990 version of C, which didn't include the `inline` keyword.

Answer (score 14):

Nope, ANSI C doesn't have `inline`.

Your second command actually overrides `-std=c99` with `-ansi` (they both affect `-std=`), so you are in effect compiling using ANSI C (no C99).

Answer (score 6):

> The inline keyword is not part of the original ANSI C standard
>   (C89) so the library does  not export any inline function definitions
>   by default. Inline functions were introduced  officially in the newer
>   C99 standard but most C89 compilers have also included inline as an 
>   extension for a long time.

quoted from [Gnu website](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Inline-functions.html)

Answer (score 4):

The reason it works fine without the ansi option at all is because gcc defaults to '-std=gnu90', which is ANSI/C89 plus extensions (one of which, not surprisingly, is support for inline functions). If you just want ANSI C support you don't need any options, unless you want strict standard compliance (which obviously may be useful if your code is going to be compiled on other compilers).